# how to add eventListener on a appended button which is dynamically copied from a hidden div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('hidden-div').innerHTML;
});
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener("click", function() {
 document.getElementById('div-main').innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="div-main">
 <input type="button" name="button1" value="button1" id="btn1">
</div>
<div id="div2">
     
</div>
<div  style="display: none;">
    <div id="hidden-div">
     <input type="button" name="button2" value="button2" id="btn2">
    </div>
</div>
```

i want to add a button2 on click button1, button2 initially is in a hidden div when i click button1 then button2  comes in div2 but when i click button2 its event doesn't work.

Comment: @Heretic, it's not a dupe. Current question is not using jQuery, hence [the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements) does not provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here fixed

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('hidden-div').innerHTML;

  document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById('div-main').innerHTML = "";
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="div-main">
  <input type="button" name="button1" value="button1" id="btn1">
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="hidden-div">
    <br><br>
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="button2" id="btn2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

`getElementById('hidden-div').innerHTML` returns a `string`, not DOM elements. That string is passed to `#div2` and parsed into **new** DOM elements, meaning the initially bound event is no longer bound on the `<input>`.

In fact, `innerHTML` is the common method to copy HTML **without** any bound events.

To keep the event you have two options:

- bind it to `#div2` instead of the button
- or don't destroy the `<input>`. Instead, append it using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Binding to `#div2`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('div2').innerHTML = document.getElementById('hidden-div').innerHTML;
});
document.getElementById('div2').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('div-main').innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="div-main">
  <input type="button" name="button1" value="button1" id="btn1">
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="hidden-div">
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="button2" id="btn2">
  </div>
</div>
```

Using `appendChild`:

```js
document.getElementById('btn1').addEventListener("click", function() {
  let children = document.getElementById('hidden-div').children;
  for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
    document.getElementById('div2').appendChild(children[i]);
  }
});
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.getElementById('div-main').innerHTML = "";
});
```

```html
<div id="div-main">
  <input type="button" name="button1" value="button1" id="btn1">
</div>
<div id="div2">

</div>
<div style="display: none;">
  <div id="hidden-div">
    <input type="button" name="button2" value="button2" id="btn2">
  </div>
</div>
```

**Important note**: moving the binding inside the `click` function means the binding will be done each time `#btn1` is clicked. It's not a problem in your case, as you're destroying and recreating the contents of `#div2` as well, but if you use the same logic to another construct, which doesn't wipe the contents, you'll bind the same function multiple times, which is dangerous as it may lead to hard to detect bugs.